# How can I display the same content on two pages with different styles?

Tags: html, css

There are two related sites.
Each has its own CSS.
Some of the content (contact info, etc) needs to be appear on a page in each site, but with the appropriate styles applied.

Is there a way to do this without duplicating the content?

Comment: You have same content for two websites? You should provide more details.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to "bring in" certain content, or do you want all of it, simply displayed differently?

Comment: You might be talking about pulling data from a db, and not CSS? More detail would be helpful. The 'duplicating content' bit really has nothing to do w/ CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is content management issue, and the correct solution for you will depend on what sort of content management you're using for these sites. If you're not using any CMS, you could still use something like PHP or JavaScript to dynamically pull content from one of the sites and display it on the second.

For example, using jQuery you could do something like this on the second site:

`$('#container-element').load('http://first-site/shared-content.html');`

Comment: Unless he wants the content to be indexed by search engines, in which case using javascript is a very bad idea. Just an FYI :)

Comment: Agreed. Using a server-side CMS of *some* kind is the best solution. But without knowing anything else, there are always options, and this was the most brief example I could think of.

Answer (score 4):

Define the same css classes in your two CSS files, and at the top of each page, bring in the proper file.

For the first page:
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/site1.css" />

Then the other page:
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/site2.css" />